# How to have regression model predict ranges

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, linear-regression, predict

I'm trying to make a model which can predict test scores. I'm currently using a simple linear regression model but receiving an accuracy score of close to 0 due to the fact that it's guessing a single number as the score. I was wondering if there was a way to have the model predict a range of about 10 numbers and if the true number is in that range it is marked as a correct guess.

[The dataset I am using](https://www.kaggle.com/spscientist/students-performance-in-exams)

[Github page with notebook](https://github.com/BobbyJoe2/Student-Performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using a `LogisticRegression`, `LogisticRegression` is in fact not for regression, it is for classification (for example, is the input data class a or b).

use `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` for linear regression, read [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) for more details

There are also many other regression algorithms that I cannot list all in an answer. If you want to use regressions other than simple naive linear regression, read [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html) for all available supervised learning algorithms scikit-learn provides, [Ridge regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ridge-regression-and-classification) and [SVR](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#regression) might be good places to start with.

Comment: Thanks, I'm fairly new to machine learning and assumed that regression in the name would mean that it is for regression.

Comment: @ThatGuy I agree that Logistic Regression is a very confusing name, but it was called this a very long time ago, so people kept it, I guess you just have to remember that Logistic Regression is a classifier algorithm.